# Why does the similar question feature not exist for the SE android app?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app

In Stack Exchange website we have a great feature which let us know if a similar question exists. It is present below the title bar.
[image]

Initially I was wondering if this feature existed in the app but after some research I found out that it doesn't (correct me if it does). So,

**Why the SE developers did not include this feature?**

They must include this feature because using the SE android app causes a lot of inconvenience and results in a lot of duplicate questions.

Comment: A similar feature request on [meta.se]: [Show similar questions in Android](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229708). Maybe it's also worth mentioning that there are no plans for further development of the SE apps (at the time), as [mentioned in the tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/android-app/info).